# R why does matrix with duplicated / repeating rownames show up with dots and numbers?

Tags: r, matrix, r-rownames

I have made some pairwise calculations and stored them in a matrix. Now I would like to label each row and column using some group labels.

```
name <- c("one name", "two name", "three name", "four name")
group <- c("group a", "group a", "group b", "group b")
groups <- data.frame(names = name, groups = group)

    z <- matrix(c(1,0,0.2,0,
                  0,1,0,1,
                  .02,0.4,1,0,
                  0,.5,0,1),
            nrow=4,
            dimnames=list(name,name))


    z <- as.matrix(z)
    rownames(z) <- groups$groups
    colnames(z) <- groups$groups
```

When I view the matrix in Rstudio, I see it as:

[image]

Why is that? Will it have any effect on my future calculations? What about the spaces that are concatenated into dots and added numbers as suffixes, can I avoid that or change the suffix to specific letters or symbols?

**EDIT:** Now I as I moved on in my analysis, I've plotted some clusters using the `library(factoextra)`. the `fviz_cluster` does not allow duplicate row.names, so I guess I'm also looking for a hack that allows that.

Comment: I can in a matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate row names are permitted in matrices but not data frames.  When viewed in RStudio, the matrix is passed to the `View()` function where it is coerced to a data frame. As part of the coercion the row names are renamed so they are unique and syntactically valid.  The original matrix object is, however, unchanged.

Comment: Thank you. The question then becomes, how to change the appearance of those suffixes and concatenations (the actual coercion).

Comment: How to change how they're displayed in the Viewer?  You can't as far as I know.  They must be unique and not contain any illegal characters.

Comment: It was more the suffix and added dots I was thinking about. I can accept the unique criteria.

Comment: Given the original row names, what output would you want?  R uses `make.names()` to create syntactically valid names for rows and columns - see `make.names(c("group a", "group a", "group b", "group b"))`.

Comment: Actually, in my case I think R uses `make.names()` and then `make.unique()`. I was thinking about adding a symbol at the end then, instead of a number or a letter, as letters in my case are deceiving.

Comment: You are right, it's both.  There are few symbols that are legal so you may run into trouble with this approach.

Comment: Do you have an idea of how I could make this possible? Maybe through a repeated symbol, such as `c("group.a", "group.a.", "group.a..")`, and how I could realize this?